# Bluetooth Headset disconnects after 10min of voice recording (like Skype calls)

Tags: audio, macos, bluetooth, headphones

As my iPhone7 doesn't have a headphone jack, I decided to get myself a wireless headset and went with the Bowers & Wilkins P5 wireless (had the wired version before and was very happy.)

On my iPhone they work perfectly! They connect automatically once I power them on and keep the connection reliably! Same on my AV-Receiver, no problems there either.

On my MacBook, on the other hand, they ALWAYS disconnect after 10 minutes of f.e. Skype-calling. I already tried other voice-calling apps such as Screenhero or even just plain voice recording like QuickTime with all other apps closed. Always the same result. They disconnect after 10 minutes. The headphones keep the connection if they just receive music, but if the send my voice to my computer, they disconnect after 10 min...

As my MacBook was full of stuff, I did a clean install of macOS Sierra two days ago and was hoping that this would maybe also resolve my BT-Problem, but it still exists.

How can I figure out what the problem is? I don't have any other BT-Speakers to check if it's just a problem with my P5s...

Are there any log-files I can check? Or any other settings that I can try? The Speaker-Settings-Pane is very limited... As is the Bluetooth-Settings-Pane...

Any hints are very much appreciated as right now my headset-bluetooth problem is very frustrating...

Comment: Try going to Settings -> Audio right after they disconnect and try selecting them again? Are they fully disconnecting or are they just releasing control of media?

Comment: They did power off. But in the meantime it's got a bit better after the latest macOS update. Only having smaller hickups now...

Comment: I've had this problem for a few years now on multiple Windows 10 laptops. It's terrible... I thought I didn't have this problem on my Mac. But I remember using it on Mac it sometimes had audio distortion. Even though the quality is great, I wont buy b&w again :( They never addressed this, probably a simple FW update could have prevented this problem for a 300 euro headset.